# Divergent Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a divergent sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n − x_{n+1} → 0$ as
$n → ∞$. Can such a sequence be bounded?

I was given this question which stumped me because isn't this a Cauchy Sequence?? Shouldn't it then converge. FYI, this is a first real analysis course so the space is complete.

Comment: $(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy Sequence. It would be if $\forall p\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ we would have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_{n+p}-x_n)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a Cauchy sequence.  Consider for example the sequence $(x_n)$ of partial sums of the series $\sum_i^\infty \frac{1}{i}$.  Then the difference of two consecutive terms of the sequence tends to zero, but the sequence is not Cauchy and in fact diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try $x_n=\sin(\sqrt n)$.

- It does not converge (and it is not a Cauchy sequence)
- $x_{n+1}-x_n\to 0$
- It is bounded

Answer (score 0):

A simple unbounded  example is $x_n=\sqrt n $.

And bounded examples exist. For example the sequence
$$
\frac12,\frac13,\frac23,\frac34,\frac24,\frac14,\frac15,\frac25,\frac35,\frac45,\frac56,\frac46,\frac36,\frac26,\frac16,\cdots
$$

Comment: The bounded sequence doesn't work - You're skipping down from $3/4$ to $1/5$ for example. $0,1/2,1, 1/2, 0, 1/3, 2/3, 1, 2/3, 1/3, 0, \dots$ will work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot to reverse the order each time.